# What is this delegate method doing?

Tags: c#

I've been reading the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on delegates and they seem straightforward. Then I was looking at some code that uses them and I saw this:

```
 public delegate void NoArguments();
 public NoArguments Refresh = null;
 Refresh = new NoArguments( Reset );
```

It's that third line that confuses me. How can you `new` a delegate? It is not an object, it's a method, or rather a delegate to a method. According to the example on the MSDN page, creating an instance of a delegate is through simple assignment, not allocaiton. Furthermore, why is the `new` for the delegate taking a parameter, `Reset`, when the delegate declaration takes no parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate is "delegate to a method", but also an object. If you look at `NoArguments` in any decompiler, you will see it is actually a class inheriting from `MulticastDelegate`, with several methods (`Invoke`, `BeginInvoke`, `EndInvoke`).

For historical reasons, C# allows you to create instances of that class using `new NoArguments(method)`. However in modern versions it also supports a shortcut notation `method` that does the same thing. In both cases, you actually do have an object of type `NoArguments` in `Refresh`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it is indeed an object, not just a function pointer.

Answer (score 4):

The `delegate` keyword indicates that what follows is essentially a function signature, so therefore, `Refresh` becomes kind of like a pointer to a function that takes no arguments.  However, to assign something to the `Refresh` pointer, you have to give it a function to point to.  In this case, it's the `Reset` function.  And further, the `Reset` function must take no arguments.

In addition, the syntax:

```
Refresh = Reset;
```

is also valid, and is just syntactic sugar for the more formal syntax:

```
Refresh = new NoArguments(Reset);
```

in both cases, you could then execute the Reset function by calling Refresh:

```
Refresh();
```

Note, however, that if you execute `Refresh()` without it having been assigned, then you could generate an exception.  The way to prevent this would be to check it against null:

```
if (Refresh != null) Refresh();
else {
    // Refresh was never assigned
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may think delegate is like a function type:

- Declare type, function returns void and have no arguments:

  ```
  public delegate void NoArguments();
  ```
- Declare variable of given type and initialize it:

  ```
  public NoArguments Refresh = null;
  ```
- Assign new object to your variable. Object is actually a function `Reset`, which must have the same signature as your delegate:

  ```
  Refresh = new NoArguments( Reset );
  ```

**UPDATE:**

You may review the following link for more details: [C# Delegates](http://www.dotnetperls.com/delegate.)